# React HOC working on some but not other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, recharts

I'm using a HOC component to bind an action to many different types of element, including SVG cells, which, when an onClick is bound normally, it works, but when I use my HOC it returns un-intended results.

Minimally reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-keldysh-3viw0

The HOC component:

```
export const withReport = Component => ({ children, ...props }) => {
    console.log(Component); //this only prints for ListItem elements for some reason

    const { dispatch } = useContext(DashboardContext);

    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log('clicked!'); //even this wont work on some.
        const { report } = props;
        if (typeof report === "undefined") return false;

        dispatch({ type: SET_ACTIVE_REPORT, activeReport: report });
        dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_REPORT });
    };

    return (
        <Component onClick={handleClick} {...props}>
            {children}
        </Component>
    );
};
```

Usage working:

```
const ListItemWIthReport = withReport(ListItem); //list item from react-mui
{items.map((item, key) => (
    <ListItemWithReport report={item.report} key={key} button>
        {/* listitem children*/}
    </ListItemWithReport>
))}
```

Usage not working:

```
const BarWithReport = withReport(Bar); //Bar from recharts
{bars.map((bar, index) => (
    <BarWithReport
        report={bar.report}
        key={index}
        dataKey={bar.name}
        fill={bar.fill}
    />
))}
```

The ListItem works 100% as anticipated, however, the bars will not render inside of the BarChart. Similarly, with a PieChart the Cells will actually render, with the correct sizes according to their values, however, props like "fill" do not appear to pass down.

Am I using the HOC incorrectly? I don't see an option other than HOC for the inside of Charts as many types of elements will be considered invalid HTML?

Comment: How are you able to access `report` in `handleClick`?

Comment: @rzwnahmd my bad, i had removed the line above it because I didn't think i was using it, the code destructured the props, let me update.

Comment: I think `children` is not valid in the render scope because `Component` (HOCs first argument) basically already is the children? That's also the only difference I can (visually) see between example one and two.

Comment: @bbortt yeah, I thought that too but, it doesn't work still even if you just return `<Component onClick={handleClick} {...props} />.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be dealing with components that have important static properties that need to be hoisted into the wrapped component or need to have ref forwarding implemented in order for their parent components to handle them. Getting these pieces in place is important, especially when wrapping components where you don't know their internals. That `Bar` component, for example, [does have some static properties](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/src/cartesian/Bar.tsx). Your HOC is making those disappear.

Here's how you can hoist these static members:

```
import hoistNonReactStatic from 'hoist-non-react-statics';

export const withReport = Component => {
  const EnhancedComponent = props => {
    const { dispatch } = useContext(DashboardContext);

    const handleClick = () => {
      const { report } = props;
      if (typeof report === "undefined") return false;

      dispatch({ type: SET_ACTIVE_REPORT, activeReport: report });
      dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_REPORT });
    };

    return (
      <Component onClick={handleClick} {...props}/>
    );
  };

  hoistNonReactStatic(EnhancedComponent, Component);
  return EnhancedComponent;
};
```

Docs on hoisting statics and ref forwarding can be found in this [handy guide to HOCs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

There may be some libraries that can take care of all these details for you. One, [`addhoc`](https://github.com/godaddy/addhoc), works like this:

```
import addHOC from 'addhoc';

export const withReport = addHOC(render => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(DashboardContext);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const { report } = props;
    if (typeof report === "undefined") return false;

    dispatch({ type: SET_ACTIVE_REPORT, activeReport: report });
    dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_REPORT });
  };

  return render({ onClick: handleClick });
});
```

Of course, if the parent component is checking child components by type *explicitly*, then you won't be able to use HOCs at all. In fact, it looks like recharts has that issue. Here you can see the chart is [defined in terms of child components](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/src/chart/BarChart.tsx#L11-L19) which are then [searched for explicitly by type](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/src/chart/generateCategoricalChart.tsx#L1010).

Comment: Can you fork the minimally reproducible example and update with these changes to show it working? I've made changes with hoistNonReactStatics locally and it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: I think you're kind of SOL because recharts explicitly expects certain child component types, so your HOCs aren't going to work as swap-in replacements. See updates. I have ideas for a workaround, stay tuned...

Comment: thanks, I've opened an issue on the recharts repo to see if the maintainers have anything else to add.

Comment: So I have like 5 different chart elements that need an onClick bound to a series and since a HOC won't work, what would you suggest for minimal code reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

I think your HOC is invalid, because not every wrapper-Component (e.g. HTML element) is basically clickable. Maybe this snipped can clarify what I am trying to say:

```
const withReport = Component => (props) => {
  const handleClick = () => console.log('whatever')

  // Careful - your component might not support onClick by default
  return <Component onClick={handleClick}  {...props} />
  // vs.
  return <div onClick={handleClick} style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
    <Component {...props} />

    {props.children}
  </div>
}

// Your import from wherever you want
class SomeClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <span onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.children}</span>
    // vs.
    return <span style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      {
        // Careful - your imported component might not support children by default
        this.props.children
      }
    </span>
  }
}

const ReportedListItem = withReport(SomeClass)

ReactDOM.render(<ReportedListItem>
  <h2>child</h2>
</ReportedListItem>, mountNode)
```

You can have the uppers or the unders (separated by `vs.`) but not crossed. The HOC using the second return (controlled wrapper-Component) is sure more save.

Comment: "when an onClick is bound normally, it works", also can't wrap the component with a div since div isn't a valid child of SVG.

Answer (score 1):

I've used 4 methods successfully to wrap Recharts components.

### First Method

Wrap the component in a HOC and use Object.Assign with some overloads.  This breaks some animation and difficult to use an active Dot on lines.  Recharts grabs some props from components before rendering them.  So if the prop isn't passed into the HOC, then it won't render properly.

```
...

function LineWrapper({
  dataOverload,
  data,
  children,
  strokeWidth,
  strokeWidthOverload,
  isAnimationActive,
  dot,
  dotOverload,
  activeDot,
  activeDotOverload,
  ...rest
}: PropsWithChildren<Props>) {
  const defaultDotStroke = 12;

  return (
    <Line
      aria-label="chart-line"
      isAnimationActive={false}
      strokeWidth={strokeWidthOverload ?? 2}
      data={dataOverload?.chartData ?? data}
      dot={dotOverload ?? { strokeWidth: defaultDotStroke }}
      activeDot={activeDotOverload ?? { strokeWidth: defaultDotStroke + 2 }}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </Line>
  );
}
export default renderChartWrapper(Line, LineWrapper, {
  activeDot: <Dot r={14} />,
});
```

```
const renderChartWrapper = <P extends BP, BP = {}>(
  component: React.ComponentType<BP>,
  wrapperFC: React.FC<P>,
  defaultProps?: Partial<P>
): React.FC<P> => {
  Object.assign(wrapperFC, component);

  if (defaultProps) {
    wrapperFC.defaultProps = wrapperFC.defaultProps ?? {};
    Object.assign(wrapperFC.defaultProps, defaultProps);
  }

  return wrapperFC;
};
```

### Second Method

---

Use default props to assign values.  Any props passed into the HOC will be overridden.

```
import { XAxisProps } from 'recharts';

import { createStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

import { themeExtensions } from '../../../assets/theme';

const useStyles = createStyles({
  tickStyle: {
    ...themeExtensions.font.graphAxis,
  },
});

type Props = XAxisProps;

// There is no actual implementation of XAxis. Recharts render function grabs the props only.

function XAxisWrapper(props: Props) {
  return null;
}

XAxisWrapper.displayName = 'XAxis';
XAxisWrapper.defaultProps = {
  allowDecimals: true,
  hide: false,
  orientation: 'bottom',
  width: 0,
  height: 30,
  mirror: false,
  xAxisId: 0,
  type: 'category',
  domain: [0, 'auto'],
  padding: { left: 0, right: 0 },
  allowDataOverflow: false,
  scale: 'auto',
  reversed: false,
  allowDuplicatedCategory: false,
  tick: { style: useStyles.tickStyle },
  tickCount: 5,
  tickLine: false,
  dataKey: 'key',
};

export default XAxisWrapper;
```

### Third Method

---

I didn't like this so I've worked around it, but you can extend the class.

```
export default class LineWrapper extends Line {

 render(){
  return (<Line {...this.props} />
 }
}
```

### Fourth Method

---

I don't have a quick example of this, but I always render the shape or children and provide functions to help.  For example, for bar cells I use this:

```
export default function renderBarCellPattern(cellOptions: CellRenderOptions) {
  const { data, fill, match, pattern } = cellOptions;
  const id = _uniqueId();
  const cells = data.map((d) =>
    match(d) ? (
      <Cell
        key={`cell-${id}`}
        strokeWidth={4}
        stroke={fill}
        fill={`url(#bar-mask-pattern-${id})`}
      />
    ) : (
      <Cell key={`cell-${id}`} strokeWidth={2} fill={fill} />
    )
  );

  return !pattern
    ? cells
    : cells.concat(
        <CloneElement<MaskProps>
          key={`pattern-${id}`}
          element={pattern}
          id={`bar-mask-pattern-${id}`}
          fill={fill}
        />
      );
}

// and

<Bar {...requiredProps}>
{renderBarCellPattern(...cell details)}
</Bar>
```

CloneElement is just a personal wrapper for Reacts cloneElement().